# Jenkinsfile Active Choice Parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I use this dsl script in Multibranch Pipeline Jenkinsfile (declarative)?

```
parameters {
    activeChoiceParam('States') {
        description('Select a state option')
        filterable()
        choiceType('SINGLE_SELECT')
        groovyScript {
            script('["Sao Paulo", "Rio de Janeiro", "Parana:selected", "Acre"]')
            fallbackScript('return ["ERROR"]')
        }
    }
    activeChoiceReactiveParam('Cities') {
        description('Active Choices Reactive parameter')
        filterable()
        choiceType('CHECKBOX')
        groovyScript {
            script('''
if (States.equals('Sao Paulo')) {
    return ['Barretos', 'Sao Paulo', 'Itu'];
} else if (States.equals('Rio de Janeiro')) {
    return ['Rio de Janeiro', 'Mangaratiba']
} else if (States.equals('Parana')) {
    return ['Curitiba', 'Ponta Grossa']
} else if (States.equals('Acre')) {
    return ['Rio Branco', 'Acrelandia']
} else {
    return ['Unknown state']
}
                       ''')
            fallbackScript('return ["Script error!"]')
        }
        referencedParameter('States')
    }
}
```

When I use this script in Jenkinsfile I get this error:

```
WorkflowScript: 23: Build parameters definitions cannot have blocks @ line 23, column 5.
       activeChoiceParam('States') {
       ^

WorkflowScript: 32: Build parameters definitions cannot have blocks @ line 32, column 9.
           activeChoiceReactiveParam('Cities') {
           ^

2 errors

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:131)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:560)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:521)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:325)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: This has been discussed at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55271 with the information in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53864574/1797006 shared there.

Answer (score 8):

This error occurs when using the Active Choices Plugin in declarative Jenkinsfiles during Jenkins Domain-Specific-Language (DSL). This is not supported [as stated by the developers](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin?focusedCommentId=165577534#comment-165577534).

This whole arrangement of plugins changeing ownership and leaving horribly outdated wiki pages full of spam leads to the danger of an immense waste of time while searching relevant information at dozens of places including "thank you"/"ping"-spammed comment sections.

Comment: It was fixed in Active Choice Plugin `v2.8.0`, and it works. But I was still getting a similar error when I had some specific set of plugins.

Answer (score 4):

I solved that problem as follows:

```
properties([ 
    parameters([
        [
            $class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
            description: 'Select a choice', 
            filterLength: 1, 
            filterable: true, 
            name: 'choice1', 
            randomName: 'choice-parameter-7601235200970', 
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 'return ["ERROR"]'
                ], 
                script: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 'return[\'aaa\',\'bbb\']'
                ]
            ]
        ], 
        [
            $class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
            description: 'Active Choices Reactive parameter', 
            filterLength: 1, 
            filterable: true, 
            name: 'choice2', 
            randomName: 'choice-parameter-7601237141171', 
            referencedParameters: 'choice1', 
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 'return ["error"]'
                ], 
                script: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 'if(choice1.equals("aaa")){return [\'a\', \'b\']} else {return [\'aaaaaa\',\'fffffff\']}'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ])
])
```

Comment: could you send example of Jenkins file where did you use it please?

Comment: @georgihagi It'd indeed be interesting where you placed this part in the Jenkinsfile. It's worth investigating whether the solution is still valid.

Comment: The above snippet by itself works. But if you I have add more parameters like `booleanParam(name: 'is_debug_mode',
                defaultValue: false)` The job does not show the is_debug_mode parameter.

Answer (score 2):

To use Active Choice parameters in a Declarative Pipeline you need to do something like this:

```
properties([
    parameters([
        choice(
            name: 'ENV',
            choices: [
                'dev',
                'prod'
            ]
        ),
        [$class: 'ChoiceParameter',
            choiceType: 'PT_RADIO',
            filterLength: 1,
            filterable: false,
            name: 'CHOICES',
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: false,
                    script: 'return ["Check Jenkins ScriptApproval page"]'
                ],
                script: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: false,
                    script: 'return ["One","Two:selected"]'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ])
])

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Print the Values') {
            steps {
                echo "Environment: ${params.ENV}"
                echo "Choice: ${params.CHOICES}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```