# How to send referencedParameters value in Jenkins pipeline for CascadeChoiceParameter to ScriptlerScript

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm declaring 2 parameters in **properties** section of a Jenkins pipeline:

- a data center (can have multiple environment types)
- an environment type

The data center is of type **ChoiceParameter**; the list is retrieved from a database; when the data center changes in the drop-down list, the environment types should populate accordingly, also from the database, through a **ScriptlerScript**.
The problem is that when changing selection on data center, nothing happens for environment types list, which is a **CascadeChoiceParameter** with **referencedParameters: 'DataCenter'**.
How should I link the referenced parameter to the scriptlet script I'm using - what do I have to send ?

The issue is with **[name:'DataCenter', value: '$DataCenter']** for second parameter - the value is not sent to the ScriptletScript when first drop-down value changes.
If I define the 2 parameters from the Jenkins interface - so not through the DSL pipeline - under **Configure** section, everything works as expected.
It's not working for me to use something other than **properties** section - I've tried using **activeChoiceParameter** inside **pipeline** section, but I get an error '*Build parameters definitions cannot have blocks @ line (...)*', which is a known issue (see first example link below).
Examples I've used: 
[Jenkinsfile Active Choice Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852261/jenkinsfile-active-choice-parameter) 
[Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter in jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410204/active-choices-reactive-reference-parameter-in-jenkins-pipeline)

```java
properties([
  parameters([
    [
      $class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
      choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
      name: 'DataCenter', 
      script: [
        $class: 'ScriptlerScript', 
        scriptlerScriptId:'getdatacenters.groovy',
        parameters: [
          [name:'StatusId', value:'']
        ]
      ]
    ],
    [
      $class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
      choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
      name: 'EnvironmentType', 
      script: [
        $class: 'ScriptlerScript',
        scriptlerScriptId:'getenvtypesbydatacenter.groovy',
        referencedParameters: 'DataCenter',
        parameters: [
          [name:'DataCenter', value: '$DataCenter']
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ])
])

pipeline {
...
```

**Expected result:** Second drop-down list populates when data center changes
**Actual result:** Nothing happens when data center changes

Pipeline with params configured in UI - behaves ok (environment types loading on data center change):

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind: **Scriptlers are not secure, you should not use them: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Scriptler+Plugin !**.

That being said, if you still want to go on and use Scriptler plugin and **CascadeChoiceParameter**, the code might look like this:

```
properties([
    parameters([
        [
            $class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
            name: 'DataCenter', 
            randomName: 'datacenter-choice-parameter-102102304304506506', 
            script: [
                $class: 'ScriptlerScript', 
                scriptlerScriptId:'getdatacenters.groovy',
                fallbackScript: [ classpath: [], script: 'return ["N/A"]']
            ]
        ],
        [
            $class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            name: 'EnvironmentType', 
            randomName: 'envtype-choice-parameter-101012020230303404', 
            referencedParameters: 'DataCenter',
            script: [
                $class: 'ScriptlerScript',
                scriptlerScriptId:'getenvtypesbydatacenter.groovy',
                fallbackScript: [ classpath: [], script: 'return ["N/A"]'],
            ]
        ]
    ])
])
```

The groovy code for **getdatacenters.groovy** for demo purposes is (but might be retrieved from a DB, as an alternative):

```
return["Dev","Prod"]
```

The groovy code for **getenvtypesbydatacenter.groovy** might look like this:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import jenkins.model.*

nodes = Jenkins.instance.globalNodeProperties
nodes.getAll(hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)
sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlserver://SQLServerHere;connectionDataHere", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")

envTypes = sql.rows("exec [DbHere].[schema].[GetEnvTypes] @DataCenter = $DataCenter").collect({ query -> query.EnvTypeName})
envTypes.add(0,'')
return envTypes
```

The most important thing to note here is that **referencedParameters: 'DataCenter'** was not inside the script block, but at the "root" level. If you need more parameters, you can separate them with comma.

Because **DataCenter** is a referenced parameter and automatically transmitted to the scriptler, **$DataCenter** variable from inside the SQL query will be mapped with its value. As a note, DataCenter should be added as parameter of the scriptler, in the UI **Parameters** section.

Credits for the solution go to CloudBees.