# Using activeChoiceReactiveParam in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How to use `activeChoiceReactiveParam` in Jenkins **pipeline**?

this is the relevant part of my jenkins file:

```
 parameters{
         activeChoiceParam('foo') {
                description('zzzz')
                filterable() 
                choiceType('SINGLE_SELECT')
                groovyScript {
                    script('xx')
                    fallbackScript('xx')
                }
            }
      }
```

Getting this error when running the build:

```
WorkflowScript: 10: Build parameters definitions cannot have blocks @ line 10, column 6.
        activeChoiceParam('foo') {
        ^
```

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64395488/jenkins-generate-new-parameters-based-on-another-parameter-value/64398244#64398244

Answer (score 2):

I think that as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56114883/9498358) post says, pipeline doesn't support activeChoiceParams.

That post is from 2 years ago but seems to be valid still; the Active Choices plugin repo links a Jenkins issue which blocks pipeline from working well with the plugin, and their [pipeline example](https://github.com/jenkinsci/active-choices-plugin#example) is similar to what they described in the post I linked.